# Adding "rate my app" to Web App Template

Tags: windows-phone-8

There's a project called Web App Template (aka WAT - http://wat.codeplex.com/) that allows you to wrap a webapp as a Windows 8 / Windows Phone 8 application. I've done that to an app, now I'm trying to add the "rate my app" feature to it. I don't see where/if I can inject code for this component to be added.

I'm following a guide here: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implement_%22Rate_My_App%22_in_under_60_seconds

I'm stuck at Step 5 - where do I add the Event Handler? There is no MainPage.xaml.cs and I don't see any similar files.

I imagine that WAT is calling another library to load a web browser. Is there some way I can inject an Event Handler and method into this library?

Comment: Ok I've found out where MainPage.xaml.cs is - nested under MainPage.xaml in the solution explorer, so I think I'm about to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry but dev questions must be asked at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not to prompt the user with 'rate my app' thing in the first opening of the app as user should be given some time to see what the app looks like and how it functions. Therefore, keeping the number of app launches and asking to rate the app after some 5th - 10th launch of app will make more sense. Besides you should check if you already prompted the user to rate your app, if so never prompt again. (Otherwise you will piss them off with 'rate my app' thing)

In order to achieve this, you should at first keep the app launch count in app settings class.

The interface for storing any kind of setting:

```
 public interface ISettingService
    {
        void Save();
        void Save(string key, object value);
        bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, object value);
        bool IsExist(string key);
        T Load<T>(string key);
        T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue);
    }
```

The rating service class that consumes the above interface to store such count and settings:

```
public class RatingService
    {
        private const string IsAppRatedKeyName = "isApprated";
        private const string TabViewCountKeyName = "tabViewCount";

        private const bool IsAppratedDefault = false;
        private const int TabViewCountDefault = 0;
        private const int ShowRatingInEveryN = 7;

        private readonly ISettingService _settingService;

        [Dependency]
        public RatingService(ISettingService settingService)
        {
            _settingService = settingService;
        }

        public void RateApp()
        {
            if (_settingService.AddOrUpdateValue(IsAppRatedKeyName, true))
                _settingService.Save();
        }

        public bool IsNeedShowMessage()
        {
            return (_settingService.GetValueOrDefault(TabViewCountKeyName, TabViewCountDefault)%ShowRatingInEveryN) == 0;
        }

        public void IncreaseTabViewCount()
        {
            int tabCount = _settingService.GetValueOrDefault(TabViewCountKeyName, TabViewCountDefault);

            if (_settingService.AddOrUpdateValue(TabViewCountKeyName, (tabCount + 1)))
                _settingService.Save();
        }

        public bool IsAppRated()
        {
            return _settingService.GetValueOrDefault(IsAppRatedKeyName, IsAppratedDefault);
        }
    }
```

This is how you will run such functionality and prompt the user to rate the app (if previously not rated) anywhere in your project (mainpage or some other page where user launches some functionality):

```
 private void RunRating()
        {
            if (!RatingService.IsAppRated() && RatingService.IsNeedShowMessage())
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Review the app?", "Would you like to review this awesome app?",
                    MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                //show message.
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    RatingService.RateApp();
                    new MarketplaceReviewTask().Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, the Rate My App component actually does have the setting to prompt after 5 and 10 times. I've actually got it working now.

Thanks for posting this simplified version of the code though, as it helps me better understand the process of how to do this in WP8. However, right now I'm still going to use the Nokia 'rate my app' component.

Comment: Your welcome. By the way, while asking such questions, I suggest not to include very specific frameworks/implementations. Rather, address your question with more like in a conceptual fashion. If you do this way, it will help more people to grasp the idea. If you think that this answer satisfies your question, you should mark it as an answer.